# JQuery CSS Selector e.fn.e.init

Tags: jquery, html, css

Sometimes I use jquery to test my css. And often I'll use a simple selector (in the Chrome Web Developer console)

I'll type in something like `$('.topclass div')` and get back

```
e.fn.e.init[125]
```

As a javascript `object` containing nodes. (Usually its quite a complex selector but sometimes its simple).

Why do I get this? Does it mean a tag is missing or my selector is wrong?

Edit: The html is basically nested divs (could it be because its getting its children divs too?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means your selection contains too many matches, and the developer tools shorten their representation in the console.

Try this in the console:

```
var a = []
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { a.push('foobar'); }
```

If you try to inspect `a`, you will see `["foobar", "foobar", "foobar", "foobar", "foobar", "foobar", "foobar", "foobar", "foobar", "foobar"]`. Now, add some more elements:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) { a.push('foobar'); }
```

Now, if you try to inspect it, you will see `Array[110]`.

Does not inherently mean your selector is wrong, but if you're expecting fewer elements, then it might be wrong.

Comment: Yes I see I changed it to $('div') and got an even higher number so it must be that. My selector is clearly wrong then